# facebook api: Is a facebook app necessary to post an an admin to a fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-apps

I am creating a php script to post some information on a fan page for which I have been designated as an admin(I didn't create it).

Do I need to have an app registered for posting to the wall of fan page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, fan page and fb app dose not have to be "connected". All you have to do is to create a fb app which will take over your right to post on fanpage as her admin. Check out section "Page Login" on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/